# Is it normal for hot mustard oil to foam strongly when ingredients are added, and why does it?

Tags: oil, spices, tempering, mustard

I noticed that my mustard oil (of indian brands, as bought outside india, from specialty grocers carrying indian ingredients) tends to foam/bloom much more than other strongly heated oils when adding dried spices, gram flour and similar ingredients.

Is this an innate behaviour of this oil or a sign of an adulterated oil? If it is innate, what is the scientific reason behind this behaviour?

Answer (score 2):

This is because all the Indian brands I know use the cold press method. In that process, some moisture is left in the oil that makes foam while heating. It's absolutely normal, and it's good that it has no chemicals. Hope this will help.

Answer (score -3):

Foam is caused because of the chemicals used.
When companies use solvent extraction to extract the last drop of oil from seed, it does leave a trace of chemical which is left behind even after refining to filter out those harmful chemicals.
Also they extract oil through high temperature mechanical extraction process prior to solvent extraction.
This means the final oil that comes out has a shorter shelf life, so companies use preservatives to increase the same.  This also plays a roll in forming those foams.

Comment: This could be a good explanation and product recommendation (which might be fine here if disclosed as such). Formatting is an issue...

Comment: I have proposed an edit to fix the case formatting.  I have also flagged the answer as spam.  The author needs to disclose their affiliation, and move the product recommendation to the end of the answer.

Comment: Welcome! Please read [How to not be a spammer](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/help/promotion), which outlines the rules of self-promotion. You may also want to read [answer] and make your text easier to read by using appropriate spelling (upper- and lower-case letters) and some basic formatting, e.g. breaking down your text into paragraphs.